# PHP: How to exec 'svn up' in Linux

Tags: php, svn, exec

I want to  visit a  url via http://xxxxx.php then my server will update automatically

I try to many way to use php execute "svn update" on my server Like:

```
system('./svn.sh', $retval);   //svn.sh contain svn up ....
system('svn up .', $retval);
system('/usr/bin/svn up --username xxx --password --- /my_path', $retval);
```

PS :I don not want to use third party php extension for subversion
Thanks !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use php for this type of task.  Rather I would use ssh to publish from the localhost to the remote host to bring that server up to date

```
ssh my_user@my_host.com "/usr/bin/svn up /my_path"
```

This is more secure and more suited for a system level task.

Comment: Genius! Thanks a lot.  Your method is much better.

Answer (score 1):

Did you test permissions on `/my_path` ? it has to be writeable by your webserver user. Additionally, you can use `exec` instead of `system` which also returns every line of output.

```
exec('/usr/bin/svn up --username xxx --password --- /my_path', $output, $retval);
print_r($output);
```

The above will give you hints where it fails

Comment: my problem is I used root execute svn co before. Now I can not change '.svn' floders permissions . Thanks!!